# converting javascript to typescript in angular4 component class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Below is the code I have in Javascript. I need to write this in a component class inside an Angular component.

Based on my understanding, `Character.prototype.placeAt()` code adds a new method or attribute to an existing object.  Or, in this case, `this.tile = tileTo;` inside `placeAt()` will update an instance of Character Object with global tileTo variable. But how do I convert this to Typescript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tileFrom:any = [1, 1];
    tileTo = [1, 1];
    function Character() {
        this.tileFrom = [1, 1];
        this.tileTo = [1, 1];
        this.tile = tileTo;

    }
    Character.prototype.placeAt = function (x, y) {
        this.tileFrom = [x, y];
        this.tileTo = [x, y];
        this.tile = tileTo;
    };
    var player = new Character();
    player.placeAt(..);

</script>
```

I tried converting it as follows but I cannot use `Character.prototype` in a typescript class as I get the error: 'duplicate identifier Character'. So how do I add `placeAt()` to the Character object?

Is it possible to access class variables without using this or sending an instance of the class?  Since this will change with context, i.e. in `placeAt()` method, `this` refers to the Character object.

```
export class GametrainComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
     tileFrom = [1, 1];
     tileTo = [1, 1];
     Character(self) {
        console.log("ss "+self.tileW)
        this.tileFrom = [1, 1];
        this.tileTo = [1, 1];
        this.tile = self.tileTo;

    };
    Character.prototype.placeAt(x:any, y:any, self) { //error duplicate identifier Character
        this.tileFrom = [x, y];
        this.tileTo = [x, y];
        this.tile = self.tileTo;

    };
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        self = this;
        this.player = new this.Character(self);
        player.placeAt(..);
    }
}
```

Please note, I am new to JavaScript and Angular.

Comment: Learn the basics of TypeScript class syntax.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: Don't use `any`.

Comment: You should declare types for all of your fields and parameters.

Comment: @SLaks i will follow those comments. Thank you. But these are not the final answer right!

Comment: That error happens because your class syntax makes no sense.  You need to follow TypeScript syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Character should be it's own class with properties and methods. It would look something like this:

character.model.ts:

```
export class Character {

  constructor(
    public tileFrom: Tile,
    public tileTo: Tile,
    public tile: Tile
  ) {}

  placeAt(x, y) {
    this.tileFrom = [x, y];
    this.tileTo = [x, y];
    this.tile = this.tileTo;
  }

}
```

gametrain.component.ts:

```
import { Character } from 'file/path';

export class GametrainComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  player: Character;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.player = new Character([1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]);
  }

  moveCharacter(tile: Tile) {
    this.player.placeAt(tile);
  }
}
```

Or if your characters are always starting at the same position then you could set those values in the `Character` class and you wouldn't have to pass it values when you create a new one.

Comment: Thank you. do you know on how to access class variables all the time as 'var' as in javascript without 'this.var' ? Since 'this' changes with context, i am not able to access class variable with 'this.var'.

Comment: Think of a class as a giant object. So instead of thinking about defining variables, you are defining properties. So you don't need to set `var` you just type the name of the property. So in the Character class you don't set a variable with `var tileForm` you define the property by just stating the name `tileForm`. In my example above you can see that's what I did with `player` in GametrainComponent. I declared a property `player` which is of type `Character`. Once you have player set to a `new Character()` you can then do `this.player.placeAt()` or `this.player.tileFrom`.

Comment: If you want to reference a property that is defined within the same class you need to use `this` because you are using a property that belongs to the class itself. So in `GametrainComponent` if I want to access player I have to use `this.player`. But I can add on to the end of that to access any properties or methods that belong to player: `this.player.tileTo`.

Comment: The same goes for calling methods within the same class. If you want to call `moveCharacter()` within the `GametrainComponent` you would need to call `this.moveCharacter()`. But remember, the class is an object. You can't think of it like the code between `<script>` tags. It will not run through every line so you can't just put `this.moveCharacter([1, 2])` on the last line of the class. You have to call it from within another method belonging to the class, from the template, or from a different class.

Comment: Thank you. I think i get its idea. Let me try.